# My MacBook won’t boot at all. Recovery won’t work

Tags: macos

I had recently upgraded to Ventura, and decided to go back to monterey. Now, I didn’t know how to do it properly, so I first wiped my disk clean and then attempted a restart to install monterey using my USB booster.

However, now when I boot up with the USB installer using the option key, it takes me to internet recovery. The problem is, the internet keeps failing. I am frequently getting -1005F, -2002F, -2003F, -2005F and it won’t boot into recovery when using cmd+R, it will also not boot when I do other combinations such as cmd+shift+opt+r and all of the combinations redirect me to internet recovery, which does not seem to work.

Edit: The internet does not have issues on any other devices except the mac. it works perfectly on all other devices.

Comment: Which specific Mac are you using?  Have you tried going to a location with stable Internet?

Comment: I am on the macbook air 2020 i3 and the internet seems to work perfectly fine

Comment: Please [edit] your question with these clarifying details.  In your question, you state that the “Internet keeps failing.”  If your Internet is stable, but the WiFi on your Mac is having problems, it’s important to make that distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem.

I managed to go ahead with my internet recovery. The only way with this issue seems to be changing DNS to 8.8.4.4.

Apple configurator did not help. Booting from USB didn't help. This was the only way for me.